# What is the easiest way to defeat Lord Rathari?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I'm struggling to defeat Lord Rathari on Nar Shaddaa.  Can someone please let me know if there is a specific strategy or prerequisite equipment needed for defeating him?

I'm a Sith Juggernaut (Level 24) and my companions are Vette and Malavai Quinn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have an easy time with him if you use Quinn, focus on his minions first, and pop your defensive cooldowns. Make sure to interrupt anything that has a casting bar.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm new to MMORPGs so could you please define "CD"?

Comment: @MikeB CDs = Cooldowns.